# Call token generation api in cypress framework

Tags: api, authentication, post, cypress, token

While calling the same token generation api from postman then i am getting a response

[image]

but same if i am calling through cypress i am getting byte array as response as shared in attached image.

[image]

Source code is of Cypress:-

```
const reqForm = new FormData();
 reqForm.append('username', 'User***');
 reqForm.append('password', "PWD@123#");
 cy.request({
    url: 'https://test.com/token-oauth',
    method: 'POST',
    body: reqForm,
    headers: {
        'accepts': "multipart/form-data",
        'authorization': 'Basic MjZiMDEyZWMtY2YxYi00OTkwLWFkM2MtMzRlNWQ5ODMwYTE5Og=='
      }
    }).then((res) => {
        debugger;
        console.log(res)
      });
```

Expected Output:-

Access token and token type

But it's giving some byte code into response

How can i call this token generation api in cypress and how i will get access token?

Comment: It is more helpful to include actual code that screenshots - can you please include the code you're trying, and what the error is you're receiving?

Comment: Hi Team,  any suggestion for this issues.